# typoscript - iterate through array?

Tags: arrays, typo3, typoscript

On my journey through TS, I came to the following question:

I need to spit out a number of links on a page (and no, HMENU is not an option).

I came up with the idea using an array for this. I already found out how to create an array:

```
color {     1 = red
     2 = green
     3 = blue}
```

Now - can I assign links to this array (including a translation for the link-text) and then iterate through the array and create typolinks?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TypoScript` although the name might suggest it, is *not* scripting language. Instead it is a configuration systax that is used to create a large render tree. You can see this tree with the `TS Object Browser`.
This tree is static and is passed as display to the `FrontendController` to render the page.

Therefore you cannot iterate in `TypoScript` as you want.

What you can do however is to create `typolinks` directly using `TEXT` objects inside a `COA` object.

```
10 = COA
10.10 = TEXT
10.10 {
  value = Linktext
  # link to page with id 1
  typolink.parameter = 1
  typolink.ATagParams = class="red"
}
10.20 {
  value = Linktext
  # link to page with id 2
  typolink.parameter = 2
  typolink.ATagParams = class="green"
}
10.20 {
  value = Linktext
  # link to page with id 3
  typolink.parameter = 3
  typolink.ATagParams = class="blue"
}
```

Alternatively you can use a `FLUIDTEMPLATE` object and pass the above TS as value. I am not sure, but it might work and you can be able to iterate through it with `Fluid`.